# Deploying Mule 3.4 CE as a jar File Using Command Prompt

Tags: eclipse, spring, mule, esb, mule-studio

I  a project running perfectly well on Mule Studio, I exported it as jar file and want to deploy it as a java app from command prompt using

> java -jar newproject.jar

It throws a ClassnotFound Exception and I noticed that the jar file does not contain all Mule dependencies. What am I doing the wrong? Its there a better approach to this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the responses, but this was how I was able to resolve it. I exported it as a runnable jar file and choose the option; Copy required libraries into a sub-folder next to the generated JAR. After exporting, I created a .bat file from here I specify the location of my java classpath. Double Clicking the bat files starts the program.

Note that I had earlier created a Class with a main method that starts the application using the procedure in this link

http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Embedding+Mule+in+a+Java+Application+or+Webapp

Answer (score 0):

You can't run Mule like that.

Take a look at the documentation:
http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/33X/Running+Mule+ESB+3

Answer (score 0):

Use the Maven Assembly Plug-in to produce a single JAR with dependencies that will contain your application and all Mule's dependencies.

See: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/descriptor-refs.html#jar-with-dependencies

Note that if you use any EE feature, you will need to use the EE Nexus as a repository. If you use DataMapper, you will have to bring a license on your classpath as well.

Keep in mind that running Mule as a single JAR will make you miss all the features provided by the standalone container, like hot application reload (obviously), classloader isolation, ...